# What does "total variation on a graph" mean? How can I visualize it?

Tags: graph-theory

There is a paper " The Total Variation on Hypergraphs -Learning on
Hypergraphs Revisited" which I am reading and I was not able to appreciate the term "total variation" in terms of graph theory. 
Further, in the paper it is also stated that this total variation on hypergraphs can be defined as Lovasv extension of the cut of the hypergraph. I also have problem in getting an intuition of what is "Lovasv Extension" actually?